# DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. contracts/GorillaNFT.sol:98:5: | 98 | _setTokenURI(tokenId, tokenURI); CAN ANYONE HELP PLZ?

Tags: contract-deployment, nft, evm

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";

contract GorillaNFT is ERC721Enumerable {
uint256 public constant MAX_NFT_SUPPLY = 16;
mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;

```
address private admin;
uint256 private goldEditionCount;
uint256 private silverEditionCount;
uint256 private bronzeEditionCount;
uint256 private specialEditionCount;

mapping(uint256 => string) private _tokenNames; // Mapping for Token-Name

mapping(address => bool) private presaleParticipants;

// URL-Pfade für die Bilder
string private constant baseURI = "https://yourwebsite.com/images/";
string private constant goldBasePath = "phase1/goldpic";
string private constant silverBasePath = "phase2/silverpic";
string private constant bronzeBasePath = "phase3/bronzepic";
string private constant specialBasePath = "phase4/specialpic";    

constructor() ERC721("GorillaNFT", "GNFT") {
    admin = msg.sender;
}

modifier onlyAdmin() {
    require(msg.sender == admin, "Only admin can perform this action");
    _;
}

modifier presaleParticipant() {
    require(presaleParticipants[msg.sender], "Address is not a presale participant");
    _;
}

function addToPresaleParticipants(address participant) external onlyAdmin {
    presaleParticipants[participant] = true;
}

function mintGoldEdition(address to, string memory name) external presaleParticipant {
    require(goldEditionCount < 4, "Gold edition limit reached");
    _mintNFT(to, name);
    goldEditionCount++;
}

function mintSilverEdition(address to, string memory name) external presaleParticipant {
    require(silverEditionCount < 4, "Silver edition limit reached");
    _mintNFT(to, name);
    silverEditionCount++;
}

function mintBronzeEdition(address to, string memory name) external presaleParticipant {
    require(bronzeEditionCount < 4, "Bronze edition limit reached");
    _mintNFT(to, name);
    bronzeEditionCount++;
}

function mintSpecialEdition(address to, string memory name) external presaleParticipant {
    require(specialEditionCount < 4, "Special edition limit reached");
    _mintNFT(to, name);
    specialEditionCount++;
}

function _mintNFT(address to, string memory name, uint256 editionType) private {
    require(totalSupply() < MAX_NFT_SUPPLY, "All NFTs have been minted");
    uint256 tokenId = totalSupply() + 1;
    _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    _tokenNames[tokenId] = name; // Saves the name for the token

    // Set token metadata, including image URLs, based on the edition
    _setTokenMetadata(tokenId, editionType);
}

function _setTokenMetadata(uint256 tokenId, uint256 editionType) private {
    require(tokenId > 0 && tokenId <= MAX_NFT_SUPPLY, "Invalid token ID");

        string memory tokenURI;

        if (editionType == 1) {
            tokenURI = string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, goldBasePath, uintToString(tokenId), ".jpg"));
        } else if (editionType == 2) {
            tokenURI = string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, silverBasePath, uintToString(tokenId), ".jpg"));
        } else if (editionType == 3) {
            tokenURI = string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, bronzeBasePath, uintToString(tokenId), ".jpg"));
        } else if (editionType == 4) {
            tokenURI = string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, specialBasePath, uintToString(tokenId), ".jpg"));
        } else {
            revert("Invalid edition type");
        }

// Set the token URI for the NFT token
_setTokenURI(tokenId, tokenURI);
```

}

```
// Help function for uint to string conversion
function uintToString(uint256 value) private pure returns (string memory) {
    if (value == 0) {
    return "0";
}
    uint256 temp = value;
    uint256 digits;
    while (temp != 0) {
    digits++;
    temp /= 10;
}
    bytes memory buffer = new bytes(digits);
    while (value != 0) {
    digits -= 1;
    buffer[digits] = bytes1(uint8(48 + uint256(value % 10)));
    value /= 10;
}
    return string(buffer);
```

}

```
// Overriding the _increaseBalance function from ERC721Enumerable
function _increaseBalance(address account, uint128 value) internal virtual override(ERC721Enumerable) {
    require(value > 0, "Value must be greater than zero");
    require(account != address(0), "Invalid account address");
    
    _balances[account] += value;

    // Call the _increaseBalance function from the parent class to increase the balance
    super._increaseBalance(account, value);
}
```

}